# Create dropdown list based on values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I'm looking to create a dropdown list based on value.

[image: Screenshot]

I have these two columns in Sheet 1 with values, Column A is the Category and Column B is the Value. On a different sheet I want to create a dropdown list of column Value based on column Category.

For example, on Sheet 2 Column A, the DropDownList choices should be only those Values that have a Sample1 value in the Category and in Column B I want all the choices in the dropdown is only those values that has Sample2 category.

I know cascading dropdown lists but I think this is a bit different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about following script?

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet1.getRange('a1:b7').getValues();
  var choises = ['Sample1', 'Sample2'];
  var list = [];
  for (var i in choises){
    var ar = data.filter(function(e){return (e[0]==choises[i])}).map(function(e){return e[1]});
    list.push(ar);
  }
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[1];
  for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++){ 
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list[i], true).build();
    var range = sheet2.getRange(2,i+1)
    range.setValue(list[i][0]);
    range.setDataValidation(rule);
  }
}
```

Dropdown list of Sample1

[image]

Dropdown list of Sample2

[image]

If I misunderstand and this isn't what you want, feel free to tell me. I'll modify this.

Comment: is it possible for this to appear on second row?

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor understanding. I modified this script just now. Please confirm it. If that wasn't the script you wanted, please let me know.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works wonderful, just one last question, how can I make this that the Sample1 will show on different Sheet, and Sample2 will show on different sheet? I want separate the dropdown on 2 different sheets.

Comment: You can put Sample1 and Sample2 to the sheet you need using getSheets(). In this script, "sheet2" is necessary to be changed.